# Python parsing xlsx based on a column name and a value

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx

I am trying to parse an xlsx following file:
enter image description [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0Zsn.png).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


data = pd.read_excel ("test.xlsx") 

ID = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['RUT23001E014'])
item_names = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= ['Riv'])
print("ID dataframe=",ID)
print("item names dataframe=",item_names)
print(ID.loc["1"])
```

What I am trying to do here, is to only return me rows where number "1" is found for a column named "RUT23001E014"

The answer that I am looking for in this case is something like that:

```
item 1 1
item 5 1
```

Since only these two items are assigned a value "1". The others who have assigned "0" I don't care about.

I have been looking at dataframe.loc function but I cannot fully figure out how do I use it to locate a particular value inside a column

*********************UPDATE*****************************

[MORE DETAILED TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwbGS.png)

So the RUTXXXXXXX are the serial numbers. Each serial number is assigned a different combination of items. Depending on a operation that I am doing, I need to know what items and quantities a specific Serial number is attached to

Comment: `data = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx").query('RUT23001E014 == 1')`

Comment: Okay thats even easier than I thought. Thank you sir. Could you also  help me understand how do I parse the result even further. The data now returned me 2 rows of information. I would like to store them in 2 different arrays. One for item name and one for the quantity. For example: ```item_array = [item1, item5]```  and  ```quantity_array = [1, 1]``` . Or even better a structure or a class.The reason I need to save is because the quantity might not be 1 all the time, it might be 2, 3 or whatever. So I need to know what quantity is each item assigned to for the particular column

Comment: Why do you need to keep 2 separate arrays? Learn the proper way to filter a DataFrame. Also, which column is the Quantity column?

Comment: I refer to a column "Quantity" the one which is named RUT23001E014. The numbers below are quantities for a certain item assigned to that serial number (RUT23001E014). Also, I need to gather a list of item names and quantities  for a particular column because I need to later do something else with that data (upload data to database). I need an item names and quantities where quantity > 0. For that particular example above, I need to save two item names ( item1, item5) and two quantities (1, 1). I believe the most conveneint way would be to save them in a class item_data

Comment: where item_data contains two variables :name and quantity. That way I can easily access item names and quantities through class. Please have a look at a more detailed example of xlsx table(I updated my initial post). It will be more clear why I need to save the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `item_names` line to this and try:

```
item_names = data[data['RUT23001E014'] == 1]
print(items_df)
```

And you can remove the line where you created `ID` - it is not useful